# Should I declare more functions or pass switch arguments to one function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

My question involves the performance gain or loss when declaring and using functions with JavaScript. Suppose I have a function, `foo()`, defined as such:

```
function foo(arg1) {
    //a simple CSS change, such as changing background color
}
```

Where `arg1` is a String used to identify an HTML element. `foo()` is triggered on a mouseover event.  The CSS change happens using jQuery, but I don't think that's important to my question. I would like to revert the CSS property back to default on a mouseout event. Would there be performance advantages of declaring another function, `foo2()`, such as:

```
function foo2(arg1) {
    //undo the CSS change
}
```

Or would it be better to redefine `foo()` as follows, using a second argument as a switch:

```
function foo(arg1,arg2) {
    if(arg2 == 'change') {
        //make the CSS change for arg1
    }else if(arg2 == 'revert') {
        //revert the change for arg1
    }
}
```

I am not concerned with the load time of the page. My goal is to minimize my amount of code, but without hampering the speed of the CSS change.

**EDIT**: `arg1` will not strictly refer to one element. It can be used to identify a set of elements, such as a class name shared by `<td>`'s in a column. This is why the `:hover` CSS selector will not do what I need to do.

**EDIT**: Again, for clarity, suppose I have a set of elements containing the class `arg1`. I want ALL of the elements to experience the CSS change even when only ONE of the elements with that class name triggers the event.

Comment: You may want to consider using the CSS `:hover` psuedoselector instead of implementing this in javascript.

Comment: The difference between both implementation would be mostly unperceivable. At this level of optimisation, think about **maintainability** over performance. And most of all, don't prematuraly optimize. That'll do more bad than good.

Comment: You shouldn't optimise for performance. You should optimise for readability. If you want to optimise for performance, _ditch jQuery_.

Comment: Why not a hover or toggle? In any case, meh: I'd use two different functions, reasonably-named, and not leave the argument passing to chance, if you really need to pass that second argument.

Comment: This is getting too many opinion-based answers, rather than answers that list the upsides and downsides of each approach. Voting to close as not constructive

Comment: I have added an edit which may add some clarification to my question.

Comment: @SimonBoudrias, I particularly like your answer, since you've actually commented on the performance difference.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to consider using the CSS `:hover` psuedoselector instead of implementing this in javascript. To use your example of changing background color:

```
#yourElementID {
    background-color: blue;
}

#yourElementID:hover { 
    background-color: green;
}
```

This will change the background color to green when the mouse is over the element, and back to blue when the mouse leaves.

Comment: I've added some information to my question to show why `:hover` isn't what I need. I apologize for the initial lack of clarity.

Comment: @MatthewPresser then you would use `.className:hover` for the selector. Your edit does not justify not being able to use a pure CSS solution.

Comment: That is incorrect, because the `:hover` event will only occur for one element. I want all elements of a given class to change background color when any element of the same class triggers the change. I've edited the question again to reflect this.

Comment: @MatthewPresser ahh I understand. In that case I believe you would need to use javascript.

Answer (score 2):

As far as the best choice for code maintenance purposes, you would want to combine the two functions into a single function. This makes your code much more readable for people in the future.

As an added bonus, combining the functions leaves the possibility of very eloquent code such as switching the CSS back using a simple conditional or negation of a `true` to `false` value etc.

Comment: I'm not sure that the one-function version is more readable. I would combine to maximise code reuse, not to improve readability.

Comment: @JanDvorak I would combine for maximal code reuse **and** readability. Also, why does the one-function approach decrease code reuse? Shall it not increase it?

Comment: @H2CO3 It does increase code reuse. I consider code reuse a reason for the one-function version, but I think two functions are (sometimes) more readable than one.

Answer (score 1):

Robert C. Martin in *Clean Code* writes

> FUNCTIONS SHOULD DO ONE THING. THEY SHOULD DO IT WELL. THEY SHOULD DO
>   IT ONLY.

He goes on to say

> Flag arguments are ugly. Passing a boolean into a function is a truly
>   terrible practice. It immediately complicates the signature of the
>   method, loudly proclaiming that this function does more than one
>   thing. It does one thing if the flag is true and another if the flag
>   is false!

While your situation is not a boolean parameter, I interpret Martin's advice to apply to any parameter used for a branch to "do more than one thing".

Comment: That said, toggling a CSS state can be considered as one action; and a function can be designed to do that thing well and that thing only.

Comment: I agree that toggle is "one thing".

Answer (score 0):

Like many others have said, if you are just changing CSS-based on whether the mouse is hovering over an HTML element or not then you should probably just do that in the CSS with `:hover:`.

If you must use jQuery for some reason this is probably the best way to do it.

```
// Add event listener for mouseover to element(s) 
$(".myHtmlElements").on("mouseover", function(){

    // 'this' always refers to the element that triggered the event in jQuery
    $(this).css("background-color", "#FF0000"); // Red
});

// Add event listener for mouseout to element(s)
$(".myHtmlElements").on("mouseout", function(){
    // 'this' always refers to the element that triggered the event in jQuery
    $(this).css("background-color", "#0000FF"); // Blue
});
```

Comment: This does not help for two reasons: 1) I am not trying to change just one element (although I realize I could change `this` to a class name to achieve that effect). 2) The class names are not fixed, and must be called dynamically.

Comment: I would just assign a class to the elements  that you will be adding the events to just so you can select them in js/jQuery. Then the `".class"` selector will match each element, and the `this` will apply individual to each matched element. If you are dynamically adding/removing elements you'll probably want to look into using delegated events like this `$(document).on("mouseover", ".class", function() { ... });`. That way you only have to bind the event listener once even if you add more elements later. http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: I do like this solution, as it is more elegant than printing `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` events for each element in question (although no more efficient in code space, since the elements are being generated dynamically with an AJAX call). However, I think it is a little more complicated in terms of comprehension for project newcomers.